# Function with all different iterated limits at origin

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Does there exist a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ s.t. all the $n!$ iterated limits
$$\lim_{x_{\sigma(1)} \to 0} \lim_{x_{\sigma(2)}\to 0} \dots \lim_{x_{\sigma(n)} \to 0} f(x_{\sigma(1)},x_{\sigma(2)},\dots,x_{\sigma(n)})$$
( $\sigma$ is a permutation of $1,2, \dots, n $) are finite and take different values? 
For example, for the function $$ f(x,y,z):=\begin{cases}\frac {x+2y+6z}{x+y+z},\, x+y+z \neq 0;\\ 0,\, x+y+z=0\end{cases}$$ only  three iterated limits at the origin are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your example,

$f(x,y,z):=\begin{cases}\frac {2x+3y}{x+y}\frac{5x+7z}{x+z}\frac{11y+13z}{y+z},\, (x+y)(x+z)(y+z)\neq 0;\\ 0,\, \textrm{otherwise}\end{cases}$

should work.

Comment: How about the general case?

Comment: Should we take $\binom n2$ multipliers of such form?